# How to create custom metadata provider in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am trying to create a custom metadata provider in .NET 6 just like we have in .NET code given below

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class IsIdentifierAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public bool IsIdentifier { get; set; }

    public IsIdentifierAttribute()
    {
        this.IsIdentifier = true;
    }

    public IsIdentifierAttribute(bool IsIdentifier)
    {
        this.IsIdentifier = IsIdentifier;
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["IsIdentifier"] = IsIdentifier;
    }
}
```

1. Is there any way to do this in .NET 6?
2. I want to get metadata for type given at runtime without using DI just like it's being done in this .NET code:

   ```
   ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(TEntity))
   ```

Please provide your response on this.

Thanks,
Sohaib (edited)

Answer (score 0):

**1 Define the custom attribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class IsIdentifierAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsIdentifier { get; set; }

    public IsIdentifierAttribute()
    {
        this.IsIdentifier = true;
    }

    public IsIdentifierAttribute(bool isIdentifier)
    {
        this.IsIdentifier = isIdentifier;
    }
}
```

**2 Define the provider**

```
public class IsIdentifierMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        var propertyAttributes = context.Attributes;
        var isIdentifierAttribute = propertyAttributes
            .OfType<IsIdentifierAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (isIdentifierAttribute != null)
        {
            context.DisplayMetadata.AdditionalValues["IsIdentifier"] = isIdentifierAttribute.IsIdentifier;
        }
    }
}
```

**3 Add the service in program.cs**

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new IsIdentifierMetadataProvider());
});
```

You want to avoid using DI, it is not recommended and we usually don’t do that since the behaviour goes against the recommended practices and design principles of these frameworks. However it can be implemented. For example called in the index action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var modelType = typeof(AppModel);
    var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
    var modelMetadata = modelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(modelType);

    // Use reflection to find properties with your custom attribute
    foreach (var propertyInfo in modelType.GetProperties())
    {
        var isIdentifierAttribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<IsIdentifierAttribute>();
        Debug.WriteLine("ok");
        if (isIdentifierAttribute != null)
        {
            // Here you can handle the metadata as needed
            // For example, you could add information to a dictionary, etc.
            Console.WriteLine("identified");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

[image]
[image]